# Gulp plumber is not working

Tags: gulp, zurb-foundation

I am trying catch errors while running a gulp task, using gulp-plumber for that. I have followed the syntax. But it just does not seems to work.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/pages/**/*.html')
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function(err){
      console.log("-----------------------",err);
     }
    }))
    .pipe(panini({
      layouts: 'src/layouts',
      partials: 'src/partials',
      helpers: 'src/helpers'
    }))
    .pipe(inky())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('tmp'));
 });
```

P.S. It turns out that gulp-plumber will catch errors given in callback not thrown errors. Try..Catch will catch those errors